# microbit file system with JavaScript

Tags: bbc-microbit

I'm trying to write to serial:

```
input.onButtonPressed(Button.B, function () { 
   basic.showNumber(1) 
   serial.redirectToUSB() 
   serial.writeLine("dit is een test1") 
   let my_data = "output.txt" 
   files.appendLine( my_data, "lll,lll,dddl,ll099" ) 
   files.readToSerial(my_data)
```

})

I followed tutorial on:
https://www.dendrite.me/media/output/mediaid/5a13f86908d73406ab61317c

and when I say:
serial.writeLine("dit is een test1")
It works great and I see it in tera term "dit is een test1"
but when I try to do it like this:
files.readToSerial(my_data)
nothing is showed :(
In the simulator it works, but on Micro:bit it doesn't show up.

Comment: Have you tried to read `my-data` a line at a time and writing each line with `serial.writeLine`

Comment: yes it gives me just variable name back and not the file :(

Comment: There are many bugs with file and serial. I have just produced the same blocks as in op but with the addition of a `for ever`  block with `show number 6`  in there, not only does the 6 not display, but the microbit also does nothing when i click button b. I have raised this as a bug on Github

Answer (score 0):

The files module is at best a beta edition.
Makecode have advised not to use it, it's unsupported.
Have you tried micropython, it has good support for file system. There is also serial support, but i have little knowledge of it